# Make TAB key cycle between inputs of one form

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I have a a number of `<form>` elements, like 2-3 forms, on one page. How can I make TAB key switch in cycle between inputs of one form, not go to next form when the last input of one form is reached?

Here is the fiddle with two forms http://jsfiddle.net/VnRBL/.

Comment: Try using [tabindex](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_tabindex.asp)

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51782054/disable-tabbing-between-links-but-inputs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable tabbing between links but inputs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51782054/disable-tabbing-between-links-but-inputs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you're looking for

```
window.onload = function() {
    var i, f = document.getElementsByTagName("FORM");
    for(i = 0; i < f.length; i++){
        (function(i){
        f[i].elements[f[i].length-1].onkeydown = function(e) {  
            var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which; 
            if(keyCode == 9) { 
                f[i].elements[0].focus();
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        };
        })(i);
    }
};
```

Check working [jsFiddle](http://jsbin.com/bilarawu/1/edit)

Answer (score 4):

First of all you shouldn't do this because it's not what the user expects.

If you really need to you have to put a key listener on your last form element and check if the user pressed the tab, in that case you give focus to the first element.

Here's an example based on your JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VnRBL/1/

```
$('#last').on('keydown', function (evt) {
    if(evt.keyCode === 9) { // Tab pressed
        evt.preventDefault();
        $('#first').focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you! Side note: this snippet goes in the `$(document).ready(function() {` section.

Comment: Either that or you can include it at the end of the `<body>`

Answer (score 1):

```
<element tabindex="number">
```

Very straightforward to implement.

Comment: @SergeyBasharov 1. You edited your question after I answered. 2. I see no reason why tabindexing wouldn't work. Post a code example. Thanks.

Comment: By editing I just made it a bit clearer that I want to cycle between elements of ONE form, not between inputs of ALL forms on the page. The solution you suggest goes from 1st to n-th element on page, not in the form. So, when I press TAB being in the last input of one form, next input is not the first input of this form, but first input of next form that has tabindex larger than this form's last input.

Comment: @SergeyBasharov I'm not a JS person but perhaps this is some inspiration to you. http://jsfiddle.net/5Vrg5/ Click the second form, then click the first form. If the User selects the first input box, the second form is disabled. An improvement to this would serve your needs.