# How do I ensure a logical tab order on a table that is loaded via ajax

Tags: javascript, accessibility

So I have this issue with accessibility where we need a table's data to be focusable by row. To accomplish this, our first instinct was to set a tabindex on the `<tr>`. At first, this seemed to work just fine. Unfortunately, the data is loaded into the table via ajax and this causes issues since the data has no awareness of tabindexes already set on the page. So for instance, let's say that the page index look like this:

1 2 3 [ ??? live data ??? ] 4 5 6

Once the data for the table is loaded, the indexes end up looking like this:

1 2 3 [ 1 2 3 4 ] 4 5 6

So now, when the user tries to tab around, the first index is at the top of the page, the second index is inside the live region, then the third is at the top of the page, and the fourth is inside of the live region and so on. Essentially, it indexes all the 1s in order, then the 2s, etc.

How do ensure that the table data is tabbable in the correct order once it's loaded?

So far, my first idea was to write a script that basically grabs everything with a tabindex and then resets the order to include the new indexed elements. This sort of works, but only if the tab indexes are in alignment with the DOM order (default/natural).

Any ideas/solutions for this?

UPDATE:
I just tried setting all of the row indexes to 0, hoping that it would just make it focusable and insert it into the "natural flow" of the tabindexes. This feels kind of weird though. Is the right approach?

Comment: If you take the tabindex off, what is the browsing order, by row or by columns; And what order would you like to have as a final result? I wouldn't use tabindex after I saw the provided situation above :) Take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24655922/make-tab-key-cycle-between-inputs-of-one-form/24657711#24657711), is this something you could use in this situation (of course, having in mind some changes)

Comment: If I take the tabindex off, then I cannot focus the table rows with the keyboard

Comment: I see, what about something like [this](http://jsbin.com/yucegepi/2/edit?html,js,output). Was playing while waiting for your response :) The inputs may have a class to not get mixed with other inputs (just in case)

Comment: So your sample there does exactly what I described as my first idea. The problem with this is that it assumes that everything on the page is intended to be displayed in the default order and will overwrite anything that is not.

Comment: Well, I thought this `1 2 3 [ 1 2 3 4 ] 4 5 6` should finally have this order `1 2 3 [ 4 5 6 7 ] 8 9 10`. Maybe I'm missing something :) The other idea would be... `1 2 3 [ incoming data -> check the tab-index of the last previous input and increment according to it increment tab-inedxes of the new inputs; then, correct/change the index of the inputs below, 4,5,6 in this case] 4 5 6`.

Comment: Just in case: is this a data table or could it be a list of rows (only if there's no real header cells)

Comment: `tabindex=0` all the rows: are there focusable items in each cells? What are yout trying to achieve? I ask this because screen readers already have a lot of shortcuts to discover content in tables... though screen readers aren't the only Assistive Technologies out there and non-disabled people also use keyboard, of course

Comment: @FelipeAls There are some focusable items in cells and they are being read out as soon as the row is focused which is good, so no problem there. What I'm trying to achieve is making the ROWS focusable in a logic tab order.

Comment: @hex494D49 the problem is that if the original layout had something like `3 1 2 [ 1 2 3 ] 4 5 6`, then the script would change it to  `1 2 3 [ 4 5 6 ] 7 8 9` when it should be `3 1 2 [ 4 5 6 ] 7 8 9`

Comment: @Sinaesthetic Oh I thought you gave up :) No, the second idea would this `3 1 2 [ 1 2 3 ] 4 5 6` change to this `3 1 2 [ 4 5 6 ] 7 8 9`. Anyhow, you should choose which part of rows to reorder, the rows above or below the news ones `[rows above][new rows][rows below]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a best practice, **rely on the natural tab order and don't use tabindex in this manner**. It will be a nightmare to attempt to set and manage the tab order manually - definitely an anti-pattern.

Screen readers already supply table navigation tools that allow users to navigate by row and by cell, so there is no need to make TR's focusable in this way.

Table nav commands for:

- NVDA: http://community.nvda-project.org/documentation/userGuide.html#SystemCaret
- JAWS: http://www.freedomscientific.com/Training/Surfs-up/Table_Reading_Commands.htm
- VoiceOver: https://www.apple.com/voiceover/info/guide/_1133.html#mchlp2723

Comment: Interesting. For what's it's worth, SSB Bart Group is requiring that we make rows focusable so that they can be navigated so now I'm curious.

Comment: Yeah - that's a heavy-handed approach, IMO.