# Disable tabbing between links but inputs

Tags: javascript

I am trying to disable tabbing between links with pure **Javascript** or with a simple css class that will affect the entire website:

Here is what i try to do

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].setAttribute("tabindex", "-1");
```

This is how it can be achieved with jquery:

`$('a').attr('tabindex', '-1');`

Comment: Sooo ... What's the problem here?

Comment: Looks like he wants to do it with JS, not with jQuery

Comment: when i press the tab key i don't want it to work on links (only on inputs i want it). So i use `tabindex` property. The problem is that i am trying to achieve it with Javascript or CSS so i can use the code for the entire website in the header of my wordpress site since it does not accept jquery code

Comment: How are people who depend on tabbing through links (such as people who depend on a screen reader or who have a physical handicap that makes it hard or impossible for them to use a mouse) supposed to use your site if you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery's `$('a').attr`:

> sets one or more attributes for every matched element.

If you do

```
document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].setAttribute
```

As you can see by the `[0]` there, you're only setting the attribute of *one* element. You need to loop through all elements instead:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a').forEach(
  a => a.setAttribute('tabindex', '-1')
);
```

```html
<input placeholder="click on me, then press tab">
<a href="example.com">link</a>
<a href="example.com">link</a>
<a href="example.com">link</a>
```

(Compare to, with no Javascript at all:)

```html
<input placeholder="click on me, then press tab">
<a href="example.com">link</a>
<a href="example.com">link</a>
<a href="example.com">link</a>
```

For old browsers that don't support `NodeList.forEach`, use the polyfill, or call the `forEach` like this instead:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
  document.querySelectorAll('a'),
  function(a){ a.setAttribute('tabindex', '-1'); }
);
```